# Jammit gem error on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, digital-ocean, jammit

I am getting following error while deploying on production. can anyone help with solution? Thanks.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `include_stylesheets' for #<#<Class:0x00000003d8e0e8>:0x00000002d0f730>):
    2: %html
    3:   %head
    4:     %title= Settings.app_name
    5:     = include_stylesheets :canvas, :media => 'all'
    6:     = include_javascripts :canvas
    7:     = javascript_include_tag 'home/custom.js.coffee'
    8:     = csrf_meta_tags
  app/views/layouts/home.html.haml:5:in `_app_views_layouts_home_html_haml___3948606540755903120_32481960'
  app/controllers/website/home_controller.rb:11:in `home'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time back I ran in to the same problem

Error `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method 'include_stylesheets' for #<#<Class:0x00000003d14ae9>:0x00000002e02770>):`

**This means that jammit gem is not loaded properly. To do this check following your web application**

1 . gem is included in your gem file

```
    gem "jammit"
```

2 . gem is loaded in your `environment.rb` file (in your case it would be `production.rb` I think)
    Find following code in environment file

```
config.before_initialize do
end
```

and write `config.gem "jammit"` in **between** block's do -- end

3 . ANd as @Dimitri Jorge said you need to run jammit b/w updating the source and symlinking to the new release. So if you are using capistrano require jammit in `deploy.rb`

```
require 'jammit'
```

and then

```
  task :generate_assets, :roles => :web do
    run "cd #{your_path_to_deploy_directory}/current && bundle exec jammit"
  end
  after "deploy", "deploy:generate_assets"
```

I hope this solves the issue. Gotcha ;)

Comment: @UandI-Thank you.I followed all these steps again but again same error.

Answer (score 0):

---

From the [Jammit documentation](https://documentcloud.github.io/jammit):

> In production, you'll want to run Jammit during deployment, somewhere in between updating the source and symlinking to the new release. Whether you're using Capistrano, Vlad, or just good 'ol Rake, it shouldn't be too hard to add a step that calls the jammit command.

Did you run the **jammit** command?